# How does gnome know which applications support GIO and GVFS?  

Tags: gnome, gvfs

How does gnome know which applications support GIO and GVFS?

Example: I open a text file in `gedit`, gvfs is used transparently, but if I open it in `kate` (KDE equivalent), it will automatically map to `~/.gvfs/<path_to_file>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exec= line from the application defines what it can handle.

Example: /`usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop` uses %U which means it can handle URLs so gvfs will be used

See http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html for details